# How to click programmatically anothers activitys button

Tags: java, android-studio

I have some data, which I'm passing to another activity, and to its arraylist item, using Intent that's no problem, but problem is that, I can't figure out how to click programmatically that another activity button, from the activity where I sent the data.

So when "save course" button been clicked, it sends the data, that I need to another activity

```
/** When "save course" button been clicked, go to ActivityCourses and there, save new course data into the item **/
number = findViewById(R.id.number_of_holes_number);
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String intentCourseName = courseName.getText().toString().trim();
        String holeNumber = number.getText().toString().trim();

        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityNewCourse.this, ActivityCourses.class);
        intent.putExtra("COURSENAME", intentCourseName);
        intent.putExtra("HOLENUMBER", holeNumber);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

now my other activity has this method, which takes that data and inserts it to an item.

```
 private void addItem() {
        mCourselist.add(new CoursesItem(getIntent().getStringExtra("COURSENAME"), "Holes:", getIntent().getStringExtra("HOLENUMBER"), R.drawable.ic_delete));
    }
```

in this activity (which get the data) I have to have now a button (addItem), which has onClickListener to perform that addItem() method.

```
    addItem = findViewById(R.id.add_item_button);
    addItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addItem();
            sortArrayList();
            saveData();
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

So my question is, how could I get rid off that button click, so instead, it just automatically add that new item to the list (after data been sent) or am I be able to somehow click addItem button from that activity where I sent the data, after data been sent?

Comment: Use  Interface  for passing data from  adapter to activity

Comment: Why not just put the addItem() function in the onCreate() method when you get the data from the intent?

Comment: P Fuster, I tried that, but every time you open that activity, it generates this empty item, which looks stupid, and also after that it just change values of that one empty item, instead of adding more items.